# ssis remove the duplicate by lookup to empty destination

Tags: ssis, etl, lookup

i have an empty destination table need to be filled from source table using SSIS ETL.

I need to remove the duplicate record then send it to the destination.
i don't want to use "sort" because it will takes time.

Thanks

Comment: is the whole record duplicated or just part of it?

Comment: If the duplicates are in the source records, use a distinct in your source query. In actual fact it will do a sort behind the scenes in the database but it will be magnitudes faster than SSIS

Answer (score 0):

change the oledb source from Table to SQLCOMMAND and use The DISTINCT option in th sql query if the entire record is duplicated. EX:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table1
```

If the duplication is in specific Column Use THE ROW_NUMBER() Function. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1,Col2 ORDER BY Col1,Col2) AS [ROWNUMBER],* FROM Table1) AS T1
WHERE T1.ROWNUMBER = 1
```